# Isabelle: how to work with matrices

Tags: matrix, isabelle, theorem-proving

I started to learn Isabelle, the theorem prover, about 2-3 weeks ago. I am still an absolute beginner and I  worked with the tutorial "Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL" so far.

The only help on matrices I found so far was to look at the [source code in the HOL library](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2011/dist/library/HOL/Matrix/Matrix.html).

Now I want to learn how to prove properties about matrices. The lambda syntax for matrices is still new to me.
Are there any tutorials or basic/intermediate examples on using matrices in Isabelle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a more recent / up-to-date entry in AFP http://afp.sourceforge.net/entries/Matrix.shtml

CeTA http://cl-informatik.uibk.ac.at/software/ceta/ is cited here as an application, so you may look there for examples how it is being used in practice.

Comment: But note that the purpose of this AFP entry is specifically executability (i.e., you can generate actual executable code for all matrix operations). For that reason some assumptions (concerning e.g., dimensions) have to be carried through all proofs, which might be slightly annoying when proving abstract properties.