# Isabelle: Issue with leibniz formula

Tags: matrix, isabelle

As I understand it, matrices in Isabelle are essentially functions and of abitrary dimension. In this setting, it is not easy to define a squared matrix (*n* x *n* matrix). Also, in a proof on paper the dimension "n" of a squared can be used in the proof. But how do I do that in Isabelle?

Leibniz Formula:

[image: Leibniz formula]

My proof on paper:

[image]

Here is a relevant excerpt of my Isabelle proof:

```
(* tested with Isabelle2013-2 (and also Isabelle2013-1) *)
theory Notepad
imports
  Main
  "~~/src/HOL/Library/Polynomial"
  "~~/src/HOL/Multivariate_Analysis/Determinants"
begin

notepad
begin
  fix C :: "('a::comm_ring_1 poly)^'n∷finite^'n∷finite"

  (* Definition Determinant (from the HOL Library, shown for reference
     see: "~~/src/HOL/Multivariate_Analysis/Determinants") *)
 have "det C =
      setsum (λp. of_int (sign p) * 
             setprod (λi. C$i$p i) (UNIV :: 'n set))
             {p. p permutes (UNIV :: 'n set)}" unfolding det_def by simp 

  (* assumtions *)
  have 1: "∀ i j. degree (C $ i $ j) ≤ 1" sorry (* from assumtions, not shown *)
  have 2: "∀ i. degree (C $ i $ i) = 1" sorry (* from assumtions, not shown *)

  (* don't have "n", that is the dimension of the squared matrix *)
  have "∀p∈{p. p permutes (UNIV :: 'n set)}. degree (setprod (λi. C$i$p i) (UNIV :: 'n set)) ≤ n" sorry (* no n! *)
end
```

What can I do in this situation?

---

**UPDATE:**

> Your type for C, a restricted version of ('a ^ 'n ^ 'n), appears to be a custom type of > yours, because I get an error when trying to use it, even after importing > Polynomial.thy. But maybe it's defined in some other HOL theory.

Unfortunately I did not write the includes in my code example, please see the updated example. But it is not a custom type, importing "Polynomial.thy" and "Determinants" should be sufficient. (I tested Isabelle version 2013-1 and 2013-2.)

> If you're using a custom definition of a matrix, there's a good chance
>   you're on your own, for the most part.

I don't belive I am using a custom definition of a matrix. 
The library `Determinants` (~~/src/HOL/Multivariate_Analysis/Determinants) has the following definition of a determinant:
`definition det:: "'a::comm_ring_1^'n^'n ⇒ 'a" where ...`. So the library uses the notion of a matrix as a vector of vectors. If my ring is over polynomials it should not make a difference in my eyes.

> Regardless, for a type such as ('a ^ 'n ^ 'n), it seems to me, you
>   should be able to write a function to return a value for the size of
>   the matrix. So if (p ^ n ^ n) is a matrix, where n is a set, then
>   maybe the cardinality of n is the n you want in your question.

This brought me on the right way. My current guess is that the following definition is helpful:

```
definition card_diagonal :: "('a::zero poly)^'n^'n ⇒ nat" where "card_diagonal A = card { (A $ i $ i) | i . True }"
```

`card` is definied in `Finite_Set`.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 140107_2040**

It's hard to make a short answer here. I only work everything for vectors, since it all gets very involved. I try to give you the function for the length of a vector as fast as possible. I then go into a big explanation on what I did to get a decent understanding of the vector type, but not necessarily for you, if you don't need it.

Reflected by the name Finite_Cartesian_Product.thy, Amine Chaieb defines a generalized finite Cartesian product. So, of course, we also get a definition for vectors and n-tuples. That it's a generalized Cartesian product is what requires the huge explanation, and what took me a long time to recognize and work through. Having said that, I'll call it a vector, since he named the type `vec`.

Everything needs to be understood in reference to what a vector is, which is defined by this definition:

```
typedef ('a, 'b) vec = "UNIV :: (('b::finite) => 'a) set"
```

This tells us that a vector is a function `f::('b::finite) => 'a`. The domain of the function is `UNIV::'b set`, which is finite and is called the index set. For example, let the index set be defined with `typedef` as `{1,2,3}`.

The codomain of the function can be any type, but let it be a set of constants `{a,b}`, defined with `typedef`. Because HOL functions are total, each element of `{1,2,3}` must get mapped to an element of `{a,b}`.

Now, consider the set of all such functions that map elements from `{1,2,3}` to `{a,b}`. There will be `2^3 = 8` such functions. I now resort to ZFC function notation, along with n-tuple notation:

```
f_1: {1,2,3} --> {a,b} == {(1,a),(2,a),(3,a)} == (a,a,a)
f_2 == {(1,a),(2,a),(3,b)} == (a,a,b)
f_3 == {(1,a),(2,b),(3,a)} == (a,b,a)
f_4 == {(1,a),(2,b),(3,b)} == (a,b,b)
f_5 to f_8 == (b,a,a), (b,a,b), (b,b,a), (b,b,b)
```

Then for any vector `f_i`, which, again, is a function, the length of the vector will be the cardinality of the domain of `f_i`, which will be 3.

I'm pretty sure your function `card_diagonal` is the cardinality of the range of the function, and I tested out a vector version of it much further down, but it basically showed me how to get the cardinality of the domain.

Here is the function for the length of a vector:

```
definition vec_length :: "('a, 'b::finite) vec => nat" where
  "vec_length v = card {i. ? c. c = (vec_nth v) i}"
declare
  vec_length_def [simp add]
```

You might want to substitute `v $ i` for `(vec_nth v) i`. The `?` is `\<exists>`.

In my example below, the `simp` method easily produced a goal `CARD(t123) = (3::nat)`, where `t123` is a type I defined with 3 elements in it. I couldn't get past that.

Anyone who wants to understand the details needs to understand the use of the `Rep_t` and `Abs_t` functions that are created when `typedef` is used to create a type `t`. In the case of `vec`, the functions would have been `Rep_vec` and `Abs_vec`, but they are renamed with `morphisms` to `vec_nth` and `vec_lambda`.

#### Will the Non-vector-specific Vector Length Please Step Forward

**Update 140111**

This should be my final update, because to completely work it out to my satisfaction, I need to know much more about instantiating type classes in general, and how to specifically instantiate type classes so that my concrete example, `UNIV::t123 set`, is finite.

I more than welcome being corrected where I may be wrong. I would much rather be reading about `Multivariate_Analysis` in a textbook than be learning how to use Isar and Isabelle/HOL like this.

By all appearances, the concept of the length of a vector of type `('a, 'b) vec` is extraordinarily simple. It is the cardinality of the universal set of the type `'b::finite`.

Intuitively, it makes sense, so I commit to the idea prematurely, but I don't permanently commit because I can't finish my example.

I added an update to the end of my "investigative" theory below.

What I hadn't done before is instantiate my example type, `t123`, a type defined with the set `{c1,c2,c3}`, as type class `top`.

The shorter story is that in pursuing `top`, `value` tipped me off that type class `card_UNIV` is involved, where `card_UNIV` is based on `finite_UNIV`. Again, the descriptive identifiers make it seem that if my type `t123` is of type class `finite_UNIV`, then I can calculate the cardinality of it with `card`, which will be the length of any vector using type `t123` as the index set.

I show some terms here which indicate what's involved, which, as usual, can be investigated by cntl-clicking on various identifiers, if you have my example theory loaded. A little more detail is in my investigative source below.

```
term "UNIV::t123 set"
term "top::t123 set"
term "card (UNIV::t123 set)" (*OUTPUT PANEL: CARD(t123)::nat.*)
term "card (top::t123 set)"  (*OUTPUT PANEL: CARD(t123)::nat.*)

value "card (top::t123 set)" (*ERROR: Type t123 not of sort card_UNIV.*)
term "card_UNIV"
term "finite_UNIV"
```

(End of update.)

**140112** Final update to the final update

It paid to not permanently commit, and though answering questions is a good way to learn, there is also downside under these circumstances.

For the vector type, the only type class that's part of the definition is `finite`, but then, above, what I'm doing involves type class `finite_UNIV`, which is in `src/HOL/Library/Cardinality.thy`.

Trying to use `card`, like with `card (UNIV::t123 set)`, won't work for type `vec` because you can't assume that type class `finite_UNIV` has been instantiated for the index set type. If I'm wrong here with what seems to be obvious now, I'd like to know.

Well, even though the function I defined, `vector_length`, doesn't try to take the cardinality of `UNIV::'b set` directly, with my example, the simplifier produces the goal `CARD(t123) = (3::nat)`.

I speculate on what that means for myself, but I haven't tracked down `CARD`, so I keep my speculations to myself.

(End of update.)

**140117** Final final final

Trying to use `value` to learn about the use of `card` led me astray. The `value` command is based on the code generator, and `value` will have type class requirements that aren't needed in general.

There's no requirement that the index set be instantiated for type class `finite_UNIV`. It's just that the logic needed to be able to use `card (UNIV::('b::finite set))` has to be in place.

It seems like the logic should already be there in `Multivariate_Analysis` for anything I've done. Anything I've said is subject to error.

(End of update.)

#### Conclusion About My Experience Here with `vec` in Multivariate_Analysis

Using generalized index sets seems overly complex, at least for me. Vectors as lists seems like what I would want, like with Matrix.thy, but maybe things need to be complex at times.

The biggest pain is using `typedef` to create a type which has a finite universal set. I don't know how to easily create finite sets. I saw a comment in the past that it's best to stay away from `typedef`. It sounds good at first, that it creates a type based on a set, but it ends up being a hassle to deal with.

[I comment further here about finite, generalized index sets being used in `vec`. I have to resort to a ZFC definition, because I have no idea where textbooks are that formalize general mathematics with type theory. This wiki article shows a generalized Cartesian product:

[Wiki: Infinite product definition using a finite or infinite index set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_products)

Key to the definition is that an infinite set can be used as the index set, such as the real numbers.

As far as using a finite set as an index set, any finite set of cardinality `n` can be put one-to-one with the natural numbers `1...n`, and a finite, natural number ordering is normally how we would use a vector.

It's not that I don't believe that someone, somewhere needs vectors with a finite index set that's not the natural numbers, but all the math I've seen for vectors and matrices is vectors of length `n::nat`, or `n::nat x m::nat` matrices.

For myself, I would think that the best vector and matrix would be based on `list`, since the component location of a list is based on natural numbers. There's a lot of computational magic that comes from using an Isabelle/HOL `list`.]

#### What I worked Through to Get the Above

It took me a lot of work to work through this. I know much less of how to use Isabelle than much more.

```
(*It's much faster to start jEdit with Multivariate_Analysis as the logic.*)
theory i140107a__Multvariate_Ana_vec_length
imports Complex_Main Multivariate_Analysis (*"../../../iHelp/i"*)   
begin

declare[[show_sorts=true]] (*Set false if you don't want typing shown.*)
declare[[show_brackets=true]]

(*---FINITE UNIVERSAL SET, NOT FINITE SET
*)

(*
First, we need to understand what `x::('a::finite)` means. It means that
`x` is a type for which the universal set of it's type is finite, where
the universal set is `UNIV::('a set)`. It does not mean that terms of type
`'a::finite` are finite sets.

The use of `typedef` below will hopefully make this clear. The following are 
related to all of this, cntl-click on them to investigate them.
*)

term "x::('a::finite)"
term "finite::('a set => bool)" (*the finite predicate*)
term "UNIV::('a set) == top"    (*UNIV is designated universal set in Set.thy.*)
term "finite (UNIV :: 'a set)"
term "finite (top :: 'a set)"

(*
It happens to be that the `finite` predicate is used in the definition of  
type class `finite`. Here are some pertinent snippets, after which I comment 
on them:

class top =
  fixes top :: 'a ("⊤")

abbreviation UNIV :: "'a set" where
  "UNIV == top"

class finite =
  assumes finite_UNIV: "finite (UNIV :: 'a set)"

The `assumes` in the `finite` type-class specifies that constant `top::'a set`
is finite, where `top` can be seen as defined in type-class `top`. Thus, any  
type of type-class `top` must have a `top` constant.

The constant `top` is in Orderings.thy, and the Orderings theory comes next 
after HOL.thy, which is fundamental. As to why this use of the constant `top` 
by type-class `finite` can make the universe of a type finite, I don't know.
*)


(*---DISCOVERING LOWER LEVEL SYNTAX TO WORK WITH
*)

(*
From the output panel, I copied the type shown for `term "v::('a ^ 'b)"`. I 
then cntl-clicked on `vec` to take me to the `vec` definition.
*)

term "v::('a ^ 'b)" 
term "v::('a,'b::finite) vec"

(*
The `typedef` command defines the `('a, 'b) vec` type as an element of a
particular set, in particular, as an element in the set of all functions of 
type `('b::finite) => 'a`. I rename `vec` to `vec2` so I can experiment with
`vec2`. 
*)

typedef ('a, 'b) vec2 = "UNIV :: (('b::finite) => 'a) set"
  by(auto)
notation 
  Rep_vec2 (infixl "$$" 90)

(*
The `morphisms` command renamed `Rep_vec` and `Abs_vec` to `vec_nth` and 
`vec_lambda`, but I don't rename them for `vec2`. To create the `vec_length`
function, I'll be using the `Rep` function, which is `vec_nth` for `vec`. 
However, the `Abs` function comes into play further down with the concrete
examples. It's used to coerce a function into a type that uses the type
construcor `vec`.
*)

term "Rep_vec2::(('a, 'b::finite) vec2 => ('b::finite => 'a))"
term "Abs_vec2::(('a::finite => 'b) => ('b, 'a::finite) vec2)"


(*---FIGURING OUT HOW THE REP FUNCTION WORKS WITH 0, 1, OR 2 ARGS
*)
  
(*
To figure it all out, I need to study these Rep_t function types. The type
of terms without explicit typing have the type shown below them, with the
appropriate `vec` or `vec2`.
*)

term "op $"
term "vec_nth"
term "op $$"
term "Rep_vec2::(('a, 'b::finite) vec2 => ('b::finite => 'a))"

term "op $ x"
term "vec_nth x"
term "op $$ x"
term "(Rep_vec2 x)::('b::finite => 'a)"

term "x $ i"
term "op $ x i"
term "vec_nth x i"
term "x $$ i"
term "op $$ x i"
term "(Rep_vec2 (x::('a, 'b::finite) vec2) (i::('b::finite))) :: 'a"

(*
No brackets shows more clearly that `x $$ i` is the curried function  
`Rep_vec2` taking the arguments `x::(('a, 'b::finite) vec2)` and 
`i::('b::finite)`.
*)
term "Rep_vec2::('a, 'b::finite) vec2 => 'b::finite => 'a"


(*---THE FUNCTION FOR THE LENGTH OF A VECTOR*)

(*
This is based on your `card_diagonal`, but it's `card` of the range of 
`vec_nth v`. You want `card` of the domain.
*)

theorem "{ (v $ i) | i. True } = {c. ? i. c = (v $ i)}"
  by(simp)
  
definition range_size :: "('a, 'b::finite) vec => nat" where
  "range_size v = card {c. ? i. c = (v $ i)}"
declare
  range_size_def [simp add]

(*
This is the card of the domain of `(vec_nth v)::('b::finite => 'a)`. I use
`vec_nth v` just to emphasize that what we want is `card` of the domain.
*)
  
theorem "(vec_nth v) i = (v $ i)"
  by(simp)

definition vec_length :: "('a, 'b::finite) vec => nat" where
  "vec_length v = card {i. ? c. c = (vec_nth v) i}"
declare
  vec_length_def [simp add]
  
theorem
  "∀x y. vec_length (x::('a, 'b) vec) = vec_length (y::('a, 'b::finite) vec)"
by(simp)

  
(*---EXAMPLES TO TEST THINGS OUT
*)

(*
Creating some constants.
*)

typedecl cT
consts
  c1::cT  
  c2::cT  
  c3::cT
  
(*
Creating a type using the set {c1,c2,c3}.
*)
  
typedef t123 = "{c1,c2,c3}" 
  by(auto)
  
(*
The functions Abs_t123 and Rep_t123 are created. I have to use Abs_t123 below
to coerce the type of `cT` to `t123`. Here, I show the type of `Abs_t123`.
*)

term "Abs_t123 :: (cT => t123)"  
term "Abs_t123 c1 :: t123"

(*
Use these `declare` commands to do automatic `Abs` coercion. I comment 
them out to show how I do coercions explicitly.
*)
  
(*declare [[coercion_enabled]]*)
(*declare [[coercion Abs_t123]]*)

(*
I have to instantiate type `t123` as type-class `finite`. It seems it should
be simple to prove, but I can't prove it, so I use `sorry`.
*)

instantiation t123 :: finite
begin
instance sorry
end

term "UNIV::t123 set"
term "card (UNIV::t123 set)"
theorem "card (UNIV::t123 set) = 3"
  try0
  oops

(*
Generalized vectors use an index set, in this case `{c1,c2,c3}`. A vector is
an element from the set `(('b::finite) => 'a) set`. Concretely, my vectors are 
going to be from the set `(t123 => nat) set`. I define a vector by defining a 
function `t123_to_0`. Using normal vector notation, it is the vector
`<0,0,0>`. Using ZFC ordered pair function notation, it is the set 
{(c1,0),(c2,0),(c3,0)}.
*)
  
definition t123_to_0 :: "t123 => nat" where
  "t123_to_0 x = 0"
declare
  t123_to_0_def [simp add]
  
(*
I'm going to have to use `vec_lambda`, `vec_nth`, and `Abs_t123`, so I create
some `term` variations to look at types in the output panel, to try to figure
out how to mix and match functions and arguments.
*)

term "vec_lambda (f::('a::finite => 'b)) :: ('b, 'a::finite) vec"

term "vec_lambda t123_to_0 :: (nat, t123) vec"

term "vec_nth (vec_lambda t123_to_0)"

term "vec_nth (vec_lambda t123_to_0) (Abs_t123 c1)"

(*
The function `vec_length` seems to work. You'd think that `CARD(t123) = 3` 
would be true. I try to cntl-click on `CARD`, but it doesn't work.
*)
  
theorem "vec_length (vec_lambda t123_to_0) = (3::nat)"
  apply(simp)
  (*GOAL: (CARD(t123) = (3::nat))*)
  oops

theorem "(vec_nth (vec_lambda t123_to_0) (Abs_t123 c1)) = (0::nat)"
  by(auto)

theorem "range_size (vec_lambda t123_to_0) = (1::nat)"
  by(auto)


definition t123_to_x :: "t123 => t123" where
  "t123_to_x x = x"
declare
  t123_to_x_def [simp add]
  
theorem "(vec_nth (vec_lambda t123_to_x) (Abs_t123 c1)) = (Abs_t123 c1)"
  by(auto)
theorem "(vec_nth (vec_lambda t123_to_x) (Abs_t123 c2)) = (Abs_t123 c2)"
  by(auto)
  

(*THE LENGTH BASED SOLELY ON THE TYPE, NOT ON A PARTICULAR VECTOR
*)

(*Update 140111: The length of a vector is going to be the cardinality of the
universal set of the type, `UNIV::('a::finite set)`. For `t123`, the following 
terms are involved.
*)

term "UNIV::t123 set"
term "top::t123 set"
term "card (UNIV::t123 set)" (*OUTPUT PANEL: CARD(t123)::nat.*)
term "card (top::t123 set)"  (*OUTPUT PANEL: CARD(t123)::nat.*)

(*
It can be seen that `card (top::t123 set)` is the same as the theorem above 
with the goal `CARD(t123) = (3::nat)`. What I didn't do above is instantiate 
type `t123` for type-class `top`. I try to define `top_t123`, but it gives me 
an error.
*)

instantiation t123 :: top
begin
definition top_t123 :: "t123 set" where
  "top_t123 = {Abs_t123 c1, Abs_t123 c2, Abs_t123 c3}"
  (*ERROR
  Clash of specifications 
  "i140107a__Multvariate_Ana_vec_length.top_set_inst.top_set_def" and
  "Set.top_set_inst.top_set_def" for constant "Orderings.top_class.top"
  *)
instance sorry
end

(*To define the cardinality of type `t123` appears to be an involved process,
but maybe there's one easy type-class that can be instantiated that gives me
everything I need. The use of `value` shows that type `t123` needs to be
type-class `card_UNIV`, but `card_UNIV` is based on class `finite_UNIV`.
Understanding it all is involved enough to give job security to a person who 
does understand it.
*)

value "card (top::t123 set)" (*ERROR: Type t123 not of sort card_UNIV.*)
term "card_UNIV"
term "finite_UNIV"

(******************************************************************************)
end
```

### The First Parts of My Answer

(Because the imports weren't shown for the source, it wasn't obvious where any of the operators were coming from. There's also the [Matrix AFP entry](http://afp.sourceforge.net/entries/Matrix.shtml) to confuse things. Additionally, other than atomic constants and variables in HOL, most everything is a function, so classifying something as a function doesn't clarify anything without some context. Providing source that won't produce errors helps. The normal entry point is `Complex_Main`. That sums up most of what I had said here. )

### Links to Related Questions

[13-05-27] [Isabelle: how to work with matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775215/isabelle-how-to-work-with-matrices)

[13-05-30] [Isabelle: transpose a matrix that includes a constant factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827937/isabelle-transpose-a-matrix-that-includes-a-constant-factor)

[13-06-25] [Isabelle matrix arithmetic: det_linear_row_setsum in library with different notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299564/isabelle-matrix-arithmetic-det-linear-row-setsum-in-library-with-different-nota)

[13-08-12] [Isabelle: maximum value in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178574/isabelle-maximum-value-in-a-vector)

[13-09-12] [Degree of polynomial smaller than a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774502/degree-of-polynomial-smaller-than-a-number)

[13-11-21] [Isabelle: degree of polynomial multiplied with constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129018/isabelle-degree-of-polynomial-multiplied-with-constant)

[13-11-26] [Isabelle: Power of a matrix (A^n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208282/isabelle-power-of-a-matrix-an)

[13-12-01] [Isabelle: difference between A * 1 and A ** mat 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317030/isabelle-difference-between-a-1-and-a-mat-1)

[14-01-17] [Isabelle: Issue with setprod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178250/isabelle-issue-with-setprod)

Comment: I added my current guess of `definition card_diagonal :: "('a::zero poly)^'n^'n ⇒ nat" where "card_diagonal A = card { (A $ i $ i) | i . True }"` to my question.

Comment: I will look into it the next two days and accept your answer. Thank you for the good suggestions!

Comment: @mrsteve, alright. I learned some stuff. The vec_length function might be the thing, or maybe not.

Comment: @mrsteve, it would be better if you unchecked my answer as the accepted answer. What I did may be able to be used, but it's not an answer, and you want unanswered questions to come up the way they should in searches and sorting. If you leave it as unanswered, that might increase the chance that someone will eventually contribute a good proof.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the essence of this question is how to obtain the integer n from a given n x n matrix, A. The difficulty here is that this integer is encoded in A's type. Nevertheless, it seems clear to me that n is actually a parameter of the problem. Although we can imagine representations of matrices that somehow store the dimension internally, from a mathematical point of view, it is natural to begin the entire development by stating "let n be a positive integer".