# Isabelle: Issue with setprod

Tags: isabelle

Does the following equality hold in Isabelle:

```
setprod f (UNIV :: 'n∷finite set) = setprod (λx. x) (f ` (UNIV :: 'n∷finite set))
```

If yes, how can I prove it?

```
(* tested with Isabelle2013-2 *)
theory Notepad
imports
  Main
  "~~/src/HOL/Library/Polynomial"
begin

notepad
begin{
fix f :: "'n∷finite ⇒ ('a::comm_ring_1 poly)"

have "finite (UNIV :: 'n∷finite set)" by simp
from this have "setprod f (UNIV :: 'n∷finite set) = setprod (λx. x) (f ` (UNIV :: 'n∷finite set))" 
sorry (* can this be proven ? *)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lemma holds only if you add the assumption `inj f` stating that `f` is injective. The lemma then follows from the library lemma `setprod_reindex_id`, which can be found using the command `find_theorems setprod image`.

`setprod_reindex_id [unfolded id_def]` gives you a generalized version of the lemma you asked for.